# Database users loop with password generator

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created some kind of code block till now, and I'm stuck. I'm selecting from table called FND_ORACLE_USERID for EBS database user schemas. Idea is to have those accounts printed in format like this (password is placeholder):
*FNDCPASS user/password 0 Y system/test11 ALLORACLE password*

Till now I have done this:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_pass  varchar(16);
  l_count number(3);
BEGIN 
    select count (*) into l_count from FND_ORACLE_USERID
    where READ_ONLY_FLAG='A';
    
  OPEN c1 for
    select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval() ch
from
(
  select distinct first_value(ch) over (partition by lower(ch)) as ch
  from (
    select substr('abcd$efghijklmn#pqrstuvw#xyzABC$DEFGHIJK$LMNPQR!STUVWXYZ1!23456789',
        level, 1) as ch
    from dual
    connect by level <= 59
    order by dbms_random.value
  )
  where rownum <= dbms_random.value(17,17)
);

  LOOP 
    FETCH c1
    INTO  l_pass;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FNDCPASS user/'||l_pass||' 0 Y system/test11 ALLORACLE '||l_pass||'');
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;  
END;
/
```

So I have started to count schemas, and I would like to stop printing new lines from above, when it reach end of count variable.

I'm not so good with plsql so please could you give some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have created password function which returns string value for my password generator code now, like this :

```
 create or replace function generic_passwd 
return varchar2 is passwd VARCHAR2(17);
begin
    select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval() ch into passwd
from
(
  select  distinct first_value(ch) over (partition by lower(ch)) as ch 
  from (
    select substr('abcd$efghijklmn#pqrstuvw#xyzABC$DEFGHIJK$LMNPQR!STUVWXYZ1!23456789',
        level, 1) as ch
    from dual
    connect by level <= 59
    order by dbms_random.value
  )
  where rownum <= dbms_random.value(17,17) 
  );
  return passwd;
  end;
  /
```

Then i called this function from my code block and it is fine to me, like this:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
DECLARE
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_user  varchar(10);
  l_passd varchar(17);
BEGIN 
  OPEN c1 for
   select oracle_username, generic_passwd() from FND_ORACLE_USERID where READ_ONLY_FLAG='A';

  LOOP 
    FETCH c1
    INTO  l_user,l_passd;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND  ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FNDCPASS '||l_user||'/'||l_passd||' 0 Y system/oracle11 ALLORACLE '||l_passd||'');
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;  
END;
/
```

Thank you for your time Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Found your own solution. Good on you. There are perhaps a couple inconsistencies, which may actually be intentional. But I think at least one or two are not:

1. The digits 3-9 can never appear in the output. You sub string
   individual characters up to the 59th in the base string, however
   that string is 66 characters in length. Perhaps the original base
   string changed but the hard coded value did not. Intentional?
2. The output cannot have a repeated character, seems intentional, but
   neither can it have a letter and the corresponding alternate case of
   that letter. I.E cannot have both "a" and "A" in the output. Intentional?
3. The Expression: [dbms_random.value](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67507)(17,17) will always return 17, at least in a piratical since as *rownum* is always as integer.
   So there is no reason to pay the function call overhead. Just use
   the equivalent rownum <= 17;
4. Just a side note: This seems to be a limited use function. If that
   is not the case then creating a standalone function is the way to
   go. If, however this limited and it is version 12.1 or higher then
   you may want to build the function directly into query using *[WITH
   FUNCTION](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-define-a-function-using-the-with-clause-in-oracle) ...*. Doing so eliminate context switch between the
   PL/SQL and SQL thus gaining performance.

The following addresses all these: See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2fa9f10136d546f02ea4ebc15fb93c3b) But i reiterate. Except for #1 and #2 above what you have will work well.

```
with function generic_passwd        --<<< define function directly as part of the query
      return varchar2            
    is
        l_generic_password varchar2(17); 
    begin 
        with base (stg) as 
             ( select 'abcd$efghijklmn#pqrstuvw#xyzABC$DEFGHIJK$LMNPQR!STUVWXYZ1!23456789' from dual)
        select xmlagg(xmlelement("r", ch)).extract('//text()').getstringval() 
          into l_generic_password
          from
              (
                 select distinct ch as ch     --<< do not allow duplicate letters, but allow lower and upper of same letter
                   from (
                          select substr(stg,level, 1) as ch
                            from base
                         connect by level <= length(stg)  --<< determine stop point from base string itself.
                           order by dbms_random.value
                        )
                  where rownum <= 17                     --<< avoid subroutine overhead that always returns same value.
              );
       return  l_generic_password; 
    end;
select username, generic_passwd() password 
  from fnd_oracle_userid;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing those findings @Belayer, and yes both are intentional. I will use this code for changing passwords of our EBS schemas, when its needed so I'm OK with that.